# Form authentication method in my ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I am currently working on an intranet for my internship (1st year comp. sci. student) - I took the last interns code and had to debug it / do some tweaks. It's going great so far; but my job right now is to go from Windows authentification method to a form based one and I'm pretty lost when it comes to it. So far, I have changed the authentication mode in my Web.config to Forms but here's the issue :

By adding

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" /> <!-- Was in comments -->
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

to my Web.config it redirects me to the basic Login page that requires me to enter my information. (Due to the authorization)

But it still displays the following content from the Site.Master :

```
<div class="float-right">
    Welcome <%: System.Environment.UserName %> - <a href='<%= Url.Action("MyProfile", "Employee")  %>'>My Profile</a> | <%: Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Deco", "Home") %>
</div> <!-- Should only display if logged in -->
```

As if I was still logged in and I could change my profile.

Is there a way to display it only when my form-based authentication is logged in?

EDIT : Additionally, what should I do to migrate from Windows auth. to a form-based one?

EDIT2 : Here is the code from my AccountController :

```
[Authorize]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    //
    // GET: /Account/Login

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOff

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        WebSecurity.Logout();
        //FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: Are you checking if user is logged and then show that code or it's there without check? Do you see your username in System.Environment.UserName?

Comment: @freshbm : There seems to be no verification, and the username is displayed. But it seems that she didn't show the username (of the intranet) but the name of my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are checking if user is logged in app to show that piece of code. If not then you can first check if user is logged then show that html using `Request.IsAuthenticated` or `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
<div class="float-right">
    Welcome <%: System.Environment.UserName %> - <a href='<%= Url.Action("MyProfile", "Employee")  %>'>My Profile</a> | <%: Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Deco", "Home") %>
</div> <!-- Should only display if logged in -->
}
```

or:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
  <div class="float-right">
        Welcome <%: System.Environment.UserName %> - <a href='<%= Url.Action("MyProfile", "Employee")  %>'>My Profile</a> | <%: Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Deco", "Home") %>
    </div> <!-- Should only display if logged in -->
}
```

Edit:

You should also change your login method to use `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate` method for authentication of users:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

also in your Logout method use `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();`

Comment: That does stop the display but the issue is that even though it doesn't display it it seems like I'm still logged in. (Perhaps through Windows Authentication). EDIT : It let's me in only if I take out the <authorization> in the Web.config, otherwise it always redirects me to the login page.

Comment: I have just added it.

Comment: I can't tell, I guess what I should do at this point is store the passwords / account lanes in the DB to then check and let the user in. So far, since I've used Windows auth. I didn't need it and I was logged into my account by default. I'll try to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For forms authentication, you should be using `User.Identity.Name` to get the username of the currently logged in user. Also check `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to see if the current user is signed in or not.

However, depending on how the project was created, you may need to add code behind the scenes to handle the logins. If you enable Forms Authentication when you create the project, ASP.NET will create it for you, but this may not have been done if the project was created to use Windows Authentication.

The following tutorial provides a good overview of how to configure and implement forms authentication:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF